how to play audio files onpress
I want to play an audio file and when the user presses the second item of the dropdown menu it stops the previous file and starts the next. I used the following code but the files play all at the same time. Another question, is soundloader cross-platform? Please explain in detail.
class Mywidget(Screen):
   sound = SoundLoader.load("listening/17.mp3")
   def check(self,*args):
    
        
        if 'news' in self.ids:
            
            sound = SoundLoader.load("listening/17.mp3")
            sound.play()
            f = open(r'listening/newspaper.txt',"r").read()
            self.ids.mytext.multiline = True
            self.ids.mytext.text = f 
            
           
        if 'practical' in self.ids:
            
            sound.stop()
            sound.unload()
            
            sound = SoundLoader.load("listening/2.mp3")
            
            sound.play()
            
            a = open(r'listening/a practical skill.txt',"r").read()
            self.ids.mytext.multiline = True
            self.ids.mytext.text = a
            
        if 'presents' in self.ids:
            sound.stop()
            sound = SoundLoader.load("listening/PRESENTS.mp3")
            sound.play()
            sound.loop = True
            b = open(r'listening/presents.txt',"r").read()
            self.ids.mytext.multiline = True
            self.ids.mytext.text = b


    ActionButton:
 id:news
 text: 'News paper and Magazine'
 on_press:root.check()

ActionButton:
 id:practical
 text: 'A practical skill'
 on_press:root.check()

ActionButton:
 id:presents
 text: 'Presents'
 on_press:root.check()


Why not use match case statement?
